# Оптимизация запроса php на удаление

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет, есть такой запрос на удаление, сейчас он нагружает проц. на 100%. Его реально оптимизировать?

foreach ($ids as $pid) {

```
            $composes = Product::getComposes($pid, $idUser);

            if ($sql->exec('select `id`,`file` from `' . TABLE_PRODUCTS_IMAGES . '` where `id_user` = "' . $sql->quotes($idUser) . '" and `id_product` = "' . $sql->quotes($pid) . '"')) {

                while ($image = $sql->getAscRow()) {
                    if (Files::delete(USERS_DIR . '/' . $sql->quotes($idUser) . '/products/images/' . $image['file'])) {
                        $sqlDelete->exec('delete from `' . TABLE_PRODUCTS_IMAGES . '` where `id_user` = ' . $sql->quotes($idUser) . ' and `id_product` = ' . $sql->quotes($pid) . ' and  `id` = ' . $sql->quotes($image['id']));
                        Files::delete(USERS_DIR . '/' . $sql->quotes($idUser) . '/products/images/preview/' . $image['file']);
                    }
                }
            }

            $sqlDelete->exec('delete from `' . TABLE_PRODUCTS_SEO . '` where `id_user` = ' . $sql->quotes($idUser) . ' and `id_product` = ' . $sql->quotes($pid));

            $sqlDelete->exec('delete from `' . TABLE_PRODUCTS_SPECIFICATIONS . '` where `id_user` = ' . $sql->quotes($idUser) . ' and `id_product` = ' . $sql->quotes($pid));

            $sqlDelete->exec('delete from `' . TABLE_PRODUCTS_SET . '` where `id_user` = ' . $sql->quotes($idUser) . ' and `id_product` = ' . $sql->quotes($pid));

            $sqlDelete->exec('delete from `' . TABLE_PRODUCTS . '` where `id_user` = ' . $sql->quotes($idUser) . ' and `id` = ' . $sql->quotes($pid));

            if ($sql->exec('select * from `' . TABLE_PRODUCTS_SET . '` where `id_user` = "' . $sql->quotes($idUser) . '" and `set` like "%' . $sql->quotes($pid) . '%"')) {
                while ($result = $sql->getAscRow()) {
                    $set = (!empty($result['set'])) ? json_decode($result['set'], true) : [];
                    unset($set[$sql->quotes($pid)]);
                    $sqlDelete->exec('delete from `' . TABLE_PRODUCTS_SET . '` where `id_product`= "' . $sql->quotes($result['id_product']) . '" and `id_user` = "' . $sql->quotes($idUser) . '"');
                }
            }

            if (!empty($composes)) {

                $main = array_shift($composes);

                $sql->exec('update `' . TABLE_PRODUCTS . '` set `id_compose` = null where `id`= "' . $main['id'] . '" and `id_user` = "' . $sql->quotes($idUser) . '"');

                foreach ($composes as $pc) {

                    $sql->exec('update `' . TABLE_PRODUCTS . '` set `id_compose` = "' . $main['id'] . '" where `id`= "' . $pc['id'] . '" and `id_user` = "' . $sql->quotes($idUser) . '"');

                    Product::setClearCacheByDependence($pc['id'], $idUser);
                }

                //return json_encode(['newcompose' => $main['id']]);
            } else {
                //return json_encode([]);
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Вы можете указать несколько таблиц в инструкции DELETE для удаления
>   строк из одной или нескольких таблиц в зависимости от конкретного
>   условия в предложении WHERE..... В предложении
>   table_references перечислены таблицы, участвующие в объединении.
>
> ```
> DELETE t1, t2 FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 INNER JOIN t3 WHERE t1.id=t2.id AND t2.id=t3.id;
> ```

Как раз для вашего случая, где только таблицы разные, а остальное одинаковое.

По 8.0 версии MySQL:

Полезная ссылка https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html

Multiple-Table Syntax

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
    tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
    FROM table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]

DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
    FROM tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
    USING table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]
```

+Для дальнейшей оптимизации DELETE:

8.2.5.3 Optimizing DELETE Statements https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete-optimization.html

> ...Чтобы быстрее удалять строки, вы можете увеличить размер кэша
>   ключей, увеличив системную переменную key_buffer_size. См. Раздел
>   5.1.1, «Настройка сервера».